# Prevent navigation to certain pages/routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, url, next.js

I have a Next.js (fix may not necessarily have anything to do with Next.js) app that I want to limit some navigation. [This page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing) in the Next.js docs mentions "you should guard against navigation to routes you do not want programmatically", but I'm unsure how to do this. Let's say I have the following pages:

```
/bikes
/boats
/cars
```

and I only want to allow a user to see `/bikes`. How would I be able to do this. I'm able to redirect from an undesired page to an acceptable page, but only after the undesired page loads. Is there a way to redirect before this (maybe by changing the URL as soon as it is changed)?

Comment: is well explained in the docs : use `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` for disable file-system routing (SSR), use `Router.beforePopState` in the client.

Comment: i guess that if you disable file-system routing you need a custom server.

Comment: I managed to get this working by using a custom server.

Comment: I achieved this by modifying `_document.tsx` and adding some control flow in the `getInitialProps` function. I didn't need to hit the database for most of my private routing logic, I just needed to verify the existence of a cookie. If you do need to hit the database for auth, it could slow down your page loads significantly.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this is an old question, however, I wish I had known this answer to it earlier than I did, so I would like to answer it for the record.

Our next.js app had a relatively complex set of permissions associated with accessing each page (with the ability to access the page, or different data presented on it) based on the authentication status of a user as well as the authorization scopes granted to them.

The solution that we used was the to return a redirect from getServerSideProps(). Normally one would return something like the following:

```
const getServerSideProps = (context) => {
  return {
    props: {
      myProp: 1
    }
  };
}
```

However, it is also possible to return a redirect. This redirect is performed on the server side *prior* to the page content being sent to the browser:

```
const getServerSideProps = (context) => {
  return {
    redirect: '/login'
  };
}
```

This is relatively new functionality - it was only pulled in towards the end of last year, and there isn't much documentation for it anywhere, but it perfectly serves this use case.